# node.html.twig gets cached while other templates do not

Tags: 8, theming

I disabled cache with the command

> drupal site:mode dev

I have overridden **html.html.twig** and **node.html.twig**.

If I change something on html.html.twig and refresh the page, the changes take place.

If I change something on node.html.twig and refresh the page, the changes do **not** appear, unless I also clear the cache or edit the node.

If I open the same page with a different browser, changes do take place, but if I make another edit and refresh, it won't work.

So I thought of some kind of browser caching, but clearing the caches in Chrome doesn't help.

How can I force Drupal to re-read node.html.twig without clearing the caches or editing a node everytime?

Thanks!

Comment: seems like the cache is still populated. Is dynamic_page_cache module enabled on your Drupal site? Seems like it is and the cache bin wasn't nulled out with drupal site:mode command. Please have a look at sites/example.settings.local.php file and check if your sites/default/settings.(local.)php was modified accordingly.

Comment: thanks, un-commenting all the bins-related lines from example.settings.local.php and copying them over to default/settings.local.php solved the issue. If you can post your answer as an actual answer I will mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`drupal site:mode dev` won't turn off all the caches. Tunning caching for dev purpose requires manual changes to the `settings.(local.)php`.

Open the `example.settings.local.php` file located in the `sites` directory and copy its content over to site's `settings.(local.)php` file.
Focus on the cache bins - in your case `render` and `dynamic_page_cache`.

```php
$settings['container_yamls'][] = DRUPAL_ROOT . '/sites/development.services.yml';
$settings['cache']['bins']['render'] = 'cache.backend.null';
$settings['cache']['bins']['dynamic_page_cache'] = 'cache.backend.null';
```

Comment: And don't forget to uncomment this line  `if (file_exists($app_root . '/' . $site_path . '/settings.local.php')) {
   include $app_root . '/' . $site_path . '/settings.local.php';
 }` in your `settings.php`